# Can we create a custom notification popup for Microsoft Teams's application

Tags: customization, microsoft-teams

Can we have a custom notification popup for Microsoft Teams's application; similar to below but with customized buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a pop up in team chat window you can use [Task module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules#task-module-deep-link-syntax) deeplink. If you want to get a popup in a meeting then you can use [Content Bubble](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/create-apps-for-teams-meetings?tabs=dotnet#notificationsignal-api).

Comment: @Tamour Ahmad - Please let us know does that help clarify.

Comment: Hi Sridevi, I wanted to customize the notification dialog which is displayed on bottom right area of screen. The ones you shared create a new dialog inside Teams after opening it.